# Complexity of reachability in Markov Chains

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity, markov-chains

Is anything known about the complexity of the following problem beyond membership in PTIME: Given a finite Markov chain $M$, an initial state $q_0$ and a set $F$ of (absorbing) states, is the probability of eventually reaching $F$ from $q_0$ greater than (or equal to) $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: seems like it should be complete for a randomized version of $L$.

Comment: mixing time of chain can be exponential.. e.g. random walk on certain directed graphs.

Comment: If F includes *all* of the absorbing states in M, and at least one state in F is reachable from $q_0$, then you will *eventually* end up in F with probability 1. If there are some absorbing states not in *F*, or you bound how much time you have, then the question is more interesting.

Comment: @Joe: Even if $F$ includes all absorbing states, there may be bottom SCCs with more than one state reachable from $q_0$. Then the probability of eventually reaching $F$ is $<1$.

Comment: @MichaelUmmels good point. I guess you could think of that whole section as a meta-state, so that while any individual state within it is not absorbing, the meta state that encapsulates the whole subset of states is absorbing.